# dynamically creating text fields lands up in duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having issues with the below code,
when I click on the link below, (extract from full code below)

```
    <a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
```

it will dynamically create a input text field... problem is it creates two input fields and I cant see why?

You should be able to duplicate the problem with the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html
 <html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">




$(function() {
var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
$('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
$('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
i++;
return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function() {
    if( i > 1  ) {
         $(this).parents('p').remove();
         i--;
}
return false;
 });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($){

var jcrop_api;

$('#target').Jcrop({
onChange:   showCoords,
onSelect:   showCoords,
onRelease:  clearCoords
},function(){
jcrop_api = this;
 });

$('#coords').on('change','input',function(e){
var x1 = $('#x1').val(),
x2 = $('#x2').val(),
y1 = $('#y1').val(),
y2 = $('#y2').val();
 jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
});

});

function showCoords(c)
 {
   $('#x1').val(c.x);
   $('#y1').val(c.y);
   $('#x2').val(c.x2);
       $('#y2').val(c.y2);
       $('#w').val(c.w);
   $('#h').val(c.h);
     };

             function clearCoords()
              {
        $('#coords input').val('');
              };


            </script> 


</head>
<body>






<form>
                    <table border=1 cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0"  width=80%>
                                            <tr><td colspan=2 align=center>
                                            <a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a>
                                            </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr><td valign=top>Alternate Urls
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                    <div id="p_scents">
                                                    </div>

                                            </td>
                                            </tr>


                    </table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Spend sometime in formatting and indenting your code. Also post only relevant code.

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem

Comment: Is there a good reason you are using jquery 1.4? it's pretty outdated now and live have been deprecated and replaced with 'on' delegates because the performance of live was so poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from using `.on` in jquery 1.4, since it has only worked as it is commonly understood since jquery 1.7. Removing the

```
$('#coords').on('change','input',function(e){
var x1 = $('#x1').val(),
x2 = $('#x2').val(),
y1 = $('#y1').val(),
y2 = $('#y2').val();
jcrop_api.setSelect([x1,y1,x2,y2]);
});
```

prevents the effect from happening.

Alternatively, switching to `.live` syntax for that event also prevents the problem.. but you should really try to use a newer version of jquery if you can. `.live` was *already deprecated* in jquery 1.4.3

Comment: Thanks this was the problem, I was merging examples I found from the web, one is using 1.4.3 and the other ver 1.9. I think that explains the use of on and live.